# how to set up AsyncStorage onPress in React-Natvie

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a problem I want to type in Input field and then hit button to set AsyncStorage. But actually what i have by this code is like this.

When i type AsyncStore is setting item and state is set also. How to make it to be set not when i type but when i hit button?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
export class SetLocation extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }
  saveData = value => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("myKey", value);
    this.setState({ myKey: value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.saved}>{this.state.myKey}</Text>
        <View>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.formInput}
            onChangeText={text => this.saveData(text)}
          />
          <Button
            title="Learn More"
            color="#841584"
            accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 30,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "stretch",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
  formInput: {
    height: 26,
    fontSize: 13,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#555555"
  },
  saved: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#333333",
    marginBottom: 5,
    marginTop: 5
  }
});

export default SetLocation;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of `onSubmitEditing` and `onPress` for the `Button` to set value in `AsyncStorage`

As mentioned in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onsubmitediting)

> **onSubmitEditing**:
>   Callback that is called when the text input's submit button is pressed. Invalid if `multiline={true}` is specified.

```
setAsyncStorage = () => {
  AsyncStorage.setItem("myKey", this.state.myKey);
}

<TextInput
   style={styles.formInput}
   onChangeText={text => this.saveData(text)}
   onSubmitEditing={this.setAsyncStorage}
/>

<Button
   title="Learn More"
   color="#841584"
   accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
   onPress={this.setAsyncStorage}
/>
```

Comment: error:
JSON value '<null>' of type NSNull cannot be converted to NSString

Comment: initialize your `this.state = {myKey: ''};` with empty string, AsyncStorage doesn't accept null values

Comment: still the same:(

Comment: Updated, there was a typo

Comment: worked just figured it out, can i ask how to after setting store redirect to another componet?

Comment: Either pass state as a prop to another component or `AsyncStorage.getItem("myKey")` if the component is not connected to the parent.

Comment: actually in App.js i have condition that checks if localstore has key and if yes rendering componet with data if not rendering componet with input field. component that is in this question is children of App.js